# Varchar and Body help on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, varchar

I have a query that I made that pulls data from a form that is being submitted by my drivers

```
SELECT DRIVER, POWER
,VARCHAR(SUBSTR(CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100)),LOCATE('FIELD:002',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 9, (LOCATE('#FIELD:003',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) - (LOCATE('FIELD:002',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 11))),10) AS TRAILER
,VARCHAR(SUBSTR(CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100)),LOCATE('FIELD:003',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 9, (LOCATE('#FIELD:004',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) - (LOCATE('FIELD:003',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 11))),10) AS REASON
,VARCHAR(SUBSTR(CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100)),LOCATE('FIELD:004',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 9, (LENGTH(CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) - (LOCATE('FIELD:004',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 10))),50) AS DESCRIPTION
FROM VMC_RETNO2 WHERE  MESSAGE_ID = '21021590' WITH UR
```

and this is how it looks in my data base!

```
#FIELD:001 
#FIELD:002 
#FIELD:003 5-Other
#FIELD:004
```

This query works great however when I try to manipulate the query so it pulls data for another form nothing returns, can you guys help me out? Thanks in advance

This is how the data looks that I need

```
Freight Bill:99095648   
Master BOL#1:1111111111 
Master BOL#2:2222222222 
Master BOL#3:3333333333 
Weight:10464            
MSF:736.234
```

Comment: You're storing multiple values of different types in the same column?

Comment: They are extracted from a column whose type is varchar

Comment: How does your modified query look like?

Comment: SELECT DRIVER, POWER
,VARCHAR(SUBSTR(CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100)),LOCATE('Freight Bill:',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 9, (LOCATE('Master BOL#1',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) - (LOCATE('Freight Bill:',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 11))),10) AS Freight_Bill
,VARCHAR(SUBSTR(CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100)),LOCATE('Master BOL#1:',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 9, (LOCATE('Master BOL#2:',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) - (LOCATE('Master BOL#1:',CAST(BODY AS VARCHAR(100))) + 11))),10) AS BOL1
FROM VMC_RETNO2 WHERE  MESSAGE_ID = '21021590' WITH UR